# Add Virtual Directory to IIS Site in Windows 10 with powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I am trying to add a virtual directory in two ways:

1º try

```
PS C:\>New-WebVirtualDirectory -Site "Default Web Site" -Name ContosoVDir -PhysicalPath C:\inetpub\contoso
```

2º try

```
## Settings
$siteName = 'Default Web Site'
$virtualDirectoryName = 'Test'
$physicalPath = 'C:\OtherDir'

## Init
$virtualDirectoryPath = "IIS:\Sites\$siteName\$virtualDirectoryName"

New-Item $virtualDirectoryPath -type VirtualDirectory -physicalPath $physicalPath
```

Both ways throw this error:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'physicalPath'.

I've tried it on Windows 10 and in Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: `New-WebVirtualDirectory` has the PhysicalPath as the parameter.. not New-Item. Whats the error when you use `New-WebVirtualDirectory` ?

Comment: The directory for the parameter -PhysicalPath has to be an existing directory, and the command needs to be run under a user account which has enough permissions to do it (e.g. I used "Run as Administrator" to start PowerShell to test New-WebVirtualDirectory).

Comment: @AndrewMorton is completely right. My mistake was running powershell without Administrator permissions. I got lost because the error doesn't mention anything about permissions...
Thank you very much.

Comment: @toscanelli That's strange, I get an error message starting with "Process should have elevated status to access IIS configuration data." if I try it without sufficient permissions. Maybe there's a version difference somewhere.